# Missing CSRF token in session

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am creating the application which can fetch the files and folder from the dropbox and will show in the web page.I have the below code.

```
$appInfo=new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);
//store CSRF token
$csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION,'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'path',$csrfTokenStore);
```

when i execute the code i got the below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\WebAuthException_BadState' with message 'Missing CSRF token in session.

Comment: What is the language you use? Please add the language's tag.

Comment: He is using PHP.i added he need to approve.i don't have edit previlage @Bestter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because of there is no `dropbox-auth-csrf-token` value in the session.When you check the ArrayEntryStore files you get to know there are function like **get(),set(),clear()**.Here clear function will unset the csrf token.

What you have to do is you need to store the csrf token value in database and when same user comes to need to fetch the value and pass it into the `ArrayEntryStore` else do the same.